# Comparing cohomology of a total complex with the cohomology of semidirect product

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, group-cohomology

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Tot}{Tot}$I have the following problem. Let $H$ and $G$ be groups such that $H$ acts on $G$, i.e., there exists a group homomorphism $H\to \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ and let $M$ be an abelian group treated as a trivial $G$- and $H$-module.

Further on, there is a double complex $C^{p,q}:= C^p(H,C^q(G,M))$ (I use here bar resolutions). To this double complex there are two spectral sequences associated, one of them is Lyndon--Hochschild--Serre spectral sequence. In particular, I know that both spectral sequences converge to $H^\ast(G\rtimes H, M)$. On the other hand, by the general construction of both spectral sequences, we know that they converge to $H^\ast(\Tot(C^{\ast \ast}))$.

My question is the following. If I have a specific cohomology class in $H^\ast(\Tot(C^{\ast \ast}))$, how can I decide to which class in $H^\ast(G\rtimes H, M)$ it corresponds? In particular, an answer to any of the following questions would do the job (I think):

1. Is there an explicit map $H^\ast(\Tot(C^{\ast \ast}))\to H^\ast(G\rtimes H, M)$ giving the isomorphism? Or is there a cochain level map?
2. Given a class in $H^2(\Tot(C^{\ast \ast}))$, how can I construct a group extension $1\to M \to E\to G\rtimes H\to 1$?

I am mostly interested in cohomology classes of degree 2 (as indicated by the second question). Also, reference would be enough.

Comment: It seems like what you would like is an explicit map $$C_*(G \rtimes H) \to Tot(C_*(G) \otimes C_*(H))$$ between certain resolutions of $\Bbb Z$ over $G \rtimes H$ - which certainly exists by the fundamental theorem of homological algebra (but I don't know if general formulas have ever been found).

Comment: @TylerLawson yes, there are recursive and explicit formulas. This is a particular case of the **twisted Eilenberg-Zilber** theorem.

Comment: @FernandoMuro that sounds similar to my answer, but possibly slightly slicker. If you know a good reference, you should consider posting it as an answer as well (I would certainly learn a thing or two)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me change the notation a little: let $\phi \colon H \to \operatorname{Aut}(N)$ be a group homomorphism, and consider $G = N \rtimes_\phi H$ (we will drop the subscript $\phi$ in the rest of this post). As usual, write $^hn$ for $\phi(h)(n)$ if $h \in H$ and $n\in N$.

The point is that the double complex $C^{\bullet\bullet}$ actually comes from a natural bi-cosimplicial abelian group, as follows:

**Definition.** Define the bisimplical set $X_{\bullet\bullet}$ via $X_{p,q} = N^{q+1}\times H^{p+1}$, where a morphism $(f,g) \colon ([p],[q]) \to ([p'],[q'])$ in $\Delta \times \Delta$ acts as
\begin{align*}
X_{p',q'} &\to X_{p,q}\\
\big(n_0,\ldots,n_{q'},h_0,\ldots,h_{p'}\big) &\mapsto \big(n_{f(0)},\ldots,n_{f(q)},h_{g(0)},\ldots,h_{g(p)}\big).
\end{align*}
Endow each $X_{p,q}$ with a $G$-action via
\begin{align*}
G \times X_{p,q} &\mapsto X_{p,q}\\
\big((n,h),(n_0,\ldots,n_q,h_0,\ldots,h_p)\big) &\mapsto \big(n\ {^hn_0},\ldots,n\ {^hn_q},hh_0,\ldots,hh_p\big)\\
\big((n,h),\big(\underline n,\underline h\big)\big) &\mapsto \big(n\ ^h\underline n,h\underline h\big).
\end{align*}
This is visibly functorial in $(p,q) \in \Delta^{\text{op}} \times \Delta^{\text{op}}$, so defines a bisimplicial $G$-set. Thus we can view $\mathbf Z[X_{\bullet\bullet}]$ naturally as a bisimplicial $\mathbf Z[G]$-module, and I claim that
$$\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf Z[G]}\big(\mathbf Z[X_{\bullet\bullet}],M\big) \cong C^{\bullet\bullet}\label{1}\tag{1}$$
as double complexes, for any $G$-module $M$ (not necessarily trivial). Indeed, note that
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf Z[G]}\big(\mathbf Z[X_{p,q}],M\big) &\cong \operatorname{Map}_G\big(X_{p,q},M\big), \\
C^{p,q} &\cong \operatorname{Map}_H\big(H^{p+1},\operatorname{Map}_N(N^{q+1},M)\big).
\end{align*}
We have a bijection $\operatorname{Map}(X_{p,q},M) \stackrel\sim\to \operatorname{Map}(H^{p+1},\operatorname{Map}(N^{q+1},M))$, taking a function $\phi \colon X_{p,q} \to M$ to $\psi \colon H^{p+1} \to \operatorname{Map}(N^{q+1},M)$ given by
$$\psi\big(h_0,\ldots,h_p\big)\big(n_0,\ldots,n_q\big) = \phi\big(n_0,\ldots,n_q,h_0,\ldots,h_p\big).$$
Now $\psi$ has image in $\operatorname{Map}_N(N^{q+1},M)$ if and only if
$$\phi\big(n\underline n,\underline h\big) = n\phi\big(\underline n,\underline h\big) \qquad \text{for all } \big(\underline n, \underline h\big) \in X_{p,q}, \text{ all } n \in N.\label{2}\tag{2}$$
The $G$-action on $\operatorname{Map}_N(N^{q+1},M)$ is given by $(gf)(\underline n) = gf(g^{-1} \cdot \underline n)$, which is trivial on $N$ by definition of $\operatorname{Map}_N$. As action of $H$, it can be written explicitly by $(hf)(\underline n) = hf(^{h^{-1}}\!\underline n)$. This means that $\psi \colon H^{p+1} \to \operatorname{Map}_N(N^{q+1},M)$ is $H$-equivariant if and only if
$$\phi\big(\underline n,h\underline h\big) = h\phi\big({^{h^{-1}}}\!\underline n,\underline h\big) \qquad \text{for all } \big(\underline n,\underline h\big) \in X_{p,q}, \text{ all } h \in H.\label{3}\tag{3}$$
Combining \eqref{2} and \eqref{3} shows that $\psi \in C^{p,q}$ if and only if $\phi(g \cdot (\underline n,\underline h)) = g \phi(\underline n,\underline h)$ for all $(\underline n,\underline h) \in X_{p,q}$ and all $g$ in either $N$ or $H$. But this means exactly that $\phi \colon X_{p,q} \to M$ is $G$-equivariant, so
$$\operatorname{Map}_G\big(X_{p,q},M\big) \stackrel\sim\to \operatorname{Map}_H\big(H^{p+1},\operatorname{Map}_N\big(N^{q+1},M\big)\big).$$
This identification is natural in $p$ and $q$, giving the isomorphism \eqref{1}. This also shows that $C^{\bullet\bullet}$ is naturally a bi-cosimplicial abelian group.

In particular, the Eilenberg–Zilber theorem ([nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Eilenberg-Zilber%20theorem#statement)) shows that the totalisation of $C^{\bullet\bullet}$ is naturally chain homotopic (!) to the diagonal $dC^\bullet$ (i.e. $dC^n = C^{n,n}$). But the diagonal of $X_{p,q}$ is just the bar resolution of $G$, so we conclude that the inclusion $dX_\bullet \hookrightarrow X_{\bullet\bullet}$ induces a chain homotopy equivalence
$$\operatorname{Tot}C^{\bullet\bullet}\simeq C^\bullet(G,M).$$
Explicit descriptions of the map follow from sufficiently effective proofs of Eilenberg–Zilber. See for instance 8.5.4 in Weibel's *An introduction to homological algebra*. (For your direction, you need to use the Alexander–Whitney map on $\mathbf Z[X_{\bullet\bullet}]$, because the direction flips when applying $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbf Z[G]}(-,M)$.)

Concretely, the map $\operatorname{Tot}(C^{\bullet\bullet}) \to C^\bullet(G,M)$ takes a $(p,q)$-cocycle $f \colon X_{p,q} \to M$ to the $(r,r)$-cocycle $X_{r,r} \to M$ given by
$$\big(n_0,\ldots,n_r,h_0,\ldots,h_r\big) \mapsto f\big(n_p,\ldots,n_r,h_0,\ldots,h_q\big),$$
where $r = p+q$. (Here I am working with inhomogeneous cocycles, i.e. $G$-equivariant maps $G^{r+1} \to M$.)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the detailed answer! However, there is one point which I don't understand. In your proof of the isomorphism (1), you're saying that the $H$-set $N^{q+1}\times H^{p+1}$ is naturally isomorphic to itself (which is of course true, but I don't know how it would help).  So did you want rather $N^{q+1}\times_{H}H^{p+1}$? And as far as I understand, this should be an $N$-set rather than $H$-set?

Comment: Sorry, are the "obvious maps" in the bisimplicial object here the ones associated to homogeneous or inhomogeneous chains?

Comment: You're right, I don't immediately see a way to apply the tensor-hom adjunction. Fixed now (more hands-on, but therefore a bit more tedious). Also tried to clarify @TylerLawson's question.

Comment: (The standard version of the tensor-hom adjunction I know is for bimodules, but I was unable to phrase it that way. The reason is roughly that $N^{q+1}$ carries a left multiplication action by $N$ and a left multiplication action by $G$, but these actions do not commute (they are in essence the same action, and $G$ might not be commutative). But there's a decent chance that a different version of the tensor-hom adjunction might do the trick here.)

Comment: One more question, though a technical one - what is the reason for writing $X_{p,q}=N^{q+1}\times H^{p+1}$ instead of $X_{p,q}=H^{p+1}\times N^{q+1}$?

Comment: There's none, except that $G$ is written as $N \rtimes H$ and not $H \ltimes N$, so $X_{p,q} = N^{q+1} \times H^{p+1}$ looks more similar (e.g. if you want to see that $X_{n,n} = G^{n+1}$, although even that requires switching the factors around a bit, I suppose).

Comment: Ok, I am actually confused with one more thing. What are face maps (horizontal and vertical) in your bisimplicial set?

Comment: I defined all the maps explicitly (face and degeneracy at once, in fact for any pair of morphisms in $\Delta \times \Delta$). To be concrete, the map $(d_i^p,1) \colon X_{p,q} \to X_{p-1,q}$ omits the coordinate $h_i$ and $(1,d_j^q) \colon X_{p,q} \to X_{p,q-1}$ omits the coordinate $n_j$.

Comment: Yes, I can see now. I was a bit confused, since there is no twisting which we would expect in a semidirect product. But now it makes sense to me. Thank you!

Comment: @IgorSikora ah right, I guess that would happen if you worked with inhomogeneous cochains, for then the boundary maps use group multiplication. The homogeneous version is easier in that regard!

Comment: Ok, I cannot resist asking this. Is there also a possibility of building a bisimplicial set which would give me on the diagonal the bar resolution of $G\rtimes H$ (rather than homogeneous resolution)? I tried to do this by hand, but I got an obvious problem with $d_0^h$ and $d_0^v$ - they are supposed to commute, but due to the non-abelianity of the semidirect product, they didn't commute.

Comment: I would claim that the homogenous one *is* the bar resolution. The only difference between the two is whether you view $\mathbf Z[G^{i+1}]$ as a free $\mathbf Z$-module of rank $\lvert G\rvert^{i+1}$ or as a free $\mathbf Z[G]$-module of rank $\lvert G\rvert^i$. From the simplicial point of view, the former is more natural, but from a $\mathbf Z[G]$-module point of the view the latter makes more sense. Even for a single group $G$, I don't know any other natural resolution that comes from a simplicial object.

Comment: Btw, I didn't write this, but the way I think about the bar resolution of $\mathbf Z[G]$ is as the Čech nerve of the 'universal cover' $G \to \{*\}$ in $G\text{-}\mathbf{Set}$. Likewise, the bisimplicial object in my answer is some sort of 'external' product of the Čech nerves of the covers $N \to \{*\}$ and $H \to \{*\}$ in $(N \rtimes H)\text{-}\mathbf{Set}$, where $N \rtimes H$ acts on $N$ via $(n,h)(m) = n\ {^hm}$ as before. Sometimes, a little topos theory doesn't hurt...

Comment: So I suppose the only observation is that the $N \rtimes H$-set $N \rtimes H$ (via left multiplication) splits as a product of $N$ and $H$ in $(N \rtimes H)\text{-}\mathbf{Set}$!